# What is the difference between " I am going in the bus " and "I am going by the bus". And which one is correct?

Tags: meaning, difference

What is the difference between " I am going in the bus " and "I am going by the bus". And which one is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase **in the bus** refers to a particular bus or to a bus the speaker and listener both know, and **by bus** refers generically to the mode of transportation.

> Are you driving to Saturday's football game?
>   --No, I'm going in the bus.

That snippet of conversation might be heard at a high school in the US, where it is common for students to take a school bus to games held at another rival school. There, *the bus* would refer to the bus normally dedicated to that purpose.

> How do you get to work in the morning? Do you drive?
>   --No, I travel by bus from my home to the terminal, and from there I take the el into the city.

Comment: No, I'm going **on the bus**; most definitely not "in the bus".

Answer (score 0):

> I am going in the bus

This can mean

- A) at this moment, you are stepping on and going inside a bus, presumably one that is about to leave, or
- B) there are several options for travel available to you and you are going select the option to travel by bus.

> I am going by the bus

This  can mean:

- A) you are walking by (as in near) a bus.
- B) there are several options for travel available to you and you are going select the option to travel by bus.
- C) you  are going somewhere and using a bus to do it, though *I am going by bus* is more idiomatic.  (Don't  try to say *I  am going in bus* - that does not work).

You probably want to say *I am going by bus*.

Answer (score -1):

Method of transportation:

I am going by bus or I am going on the bus.

*in the bus* is not used here unless you mean: I'm going on top of the bus.

She's sitting in the bus, not in the car. [OK]

I **got on the bus** at 2 o'clock.

Comment: Please disregard downvoters here.